# Laravel eloquent-relationships does not work in my case

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have 2 table

Subscriptions Table

```
id char(36) | other column
```

Licenses Table

```
id bigint(20) | license_key (string) | subscription_id char(36)
```

Model Subscription.php

```
protected $with = ['licenses'];

public function licenses()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\License', 'subscription_id');
}
```

Eager Loading work for mostly case, but `subscription_id = 6e20af64-81e6-428e-b9db-52317d1e478e`

`subscription_id = 6e20af64-81e6-428e-b9db-52317d1e478e` exist in Licenses Table

This is QueryLog:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `subscriptions` where `subscriptions`.`id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "6e20af64-81e6-428e-b9db-52317d1e478e"
    ]
    "time" => 3.9
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `licenses` where `licenses`.`subscription_id` in (9223372036854775807)"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 4.73
  ]
]
```

Why it does not work with only this subscription_id?

my env:

```
"laravel/framework": "6.20.17",

php: 7.4.14
```

Comment: did you try with: return $this->hasMany(License::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key'); ?

Comment: as it says, `// In Laravel 6.0+ make sure to also set $keyType         
    protected $keyType = 'string';`

Answer (score 1):

As your primary key seems to be a UUID, you need to tell Laravel that your PK is a string. I use this very handy trait for this. Not only does it set the key type to `string` and disables incrementing the PK but also generates new UUIDs when creating new Models.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait HasPrimaryUuid
{
    protected static function bootUsesPrimaryUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (!$model->getKey()) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string)Str::uuid();
            }
        });
    }

    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

Simply `use` this trait in your models like with other traits:

```php
class MyModel extends Model {
    use HasPrimaryUuid;
    
    // ...

}
```